# json autocomplete for two fields

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I want to autocomplete the two columns in my `json url`.

Here's my script:

```
<script>
        var options = {
        url: "all.json",
        getValue: "code",
        list: {  
        match: {
        enabled: false
        }
        },
        };
        $("#data-categories").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
```

The autocomplete works for the **code** column only. I want to autocomplete also the `name` and `code` columns. This is how I add the multiple column.

In all,`json url` the sample code is like this:

```
[{"code":"2GO","market":"","name":"2GO Group   Inc","codeName":"","sector":"Industrials","subIndustry":"Marine Shipping","pseID":null,"pseSecID":null,"industy":"Transportation & Logistics"}]
```

Kindly help me to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you give some more information about your code ..

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var options = {
        url: "all.json",
        data : { 'firstvalue': firstvalue,'secondvalue': secondvalue },
        list: {  
        match: {
        enabled: false
        }
        },
        };
        $("#data-categories").easyAutocomplete(options);
```